# ResultSet not iterating values of specified column

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I've got a method, that returns the value of a ResultSet query via a date object. The snag is that, in my output, it only returns the last value in the particular column. How do i go about this?

```
 public Date getTime(){
      Date date = null;
      DateFormat format;

      try {

              Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
              Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");

              Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

              ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM error_log WHERE service_source = 'Billbox' ");

              while (result.next()) {  //retrieve data
                  String ds = result.getString("error_date");
                  format = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy H:m:s a");

                  date = (Date)format.parse(ds);  

              }
              con.close();

          } catch (Exception ex) {
              Logger.getLogger(LogDB.class.getName()).log( 
                            Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          }
      return date;
  }
```

Then in my main method:

```
  public static void main(String args[]){        
      TestA ea = new TestA();
      Date ss = ea.getTime();
      System.out.println(ss);
  }
```

But this only returns the last value in my query. how can i print out other (the olders) along with it?

Comment: Hello gbade, if any of the answer above solves your problem, please accept one !

Comment: yes pick one and click on the hook in the left corner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fill a list of dates from your query results. Try this :

```
  public List<Date> getTime(){
      List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
      DateFormat format;

      try {

          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");

          Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

          ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM error_log WHERE service_source = 'Billbox' ");

          while (result.next()) {  //retrieve data
              String ds = result.getString("error_date");
              format = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy H:m:s a");

              dates.add((Date)format.parse(ds));  

          }
          con.close();

      } catch (Exception ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(LogDB.class.getName()).log( 
                        Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
      return dates;
  }
```

Comment: Please refer to my comment on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17596064/1065197)

Comment: After your edit, you should return a `List<Date>` instead of `ArrayList<Date>` otherwise the code won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the while loop you asign to date the last value.
Change your method as

```
public List<Date> getTime(){
```

You can try

```
List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
```

and then inside your while loop;

```
while (result.next()) {  //retrieve data
                  String ds = result.getString("error_date");
                  format = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy H:m:s a");

                  date = (Date)format.parse(ds);  
                  dates.put(date);


              }

return dates;
```

Comment: It would be better using `List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();`. Refer to [What does it mean to “program to an interface”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197)

Answer (score 0):

just:

```
        List<Date> lDateDb = new ArrayList<Date>();
        while (result.next()) {  //retrieve data
              String ds = result.getString("error_date");
              format = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy H:m:s a");

              date = (Date)format.parse(ds);  
              lDateDb.add(date);
          }
        return lDateDb;
```

change return type of `getTime` to `List<Date>` and change the main to:

```
public static void main(String args[]){        
  TestA ea = new TestA();
  List<Date> lAllDate = ea.getTime();
  for (Date lDate : lAllDate)
  System.out.println(lDate );
}
```